# Open source firmware (e.g. OpenWRT) supporting manufacturers?

Tags: law, hardware, firmware

According to recent news the US FCC has targeted the network devices enforcing manufacturers to lock down firmwares to prevent installation custom firmwares like OpenWRT.

You can read the whole article here: [New FCC Rules May Prevent Installing OpenWRT on WiFi Routers](http://www.cnx-software.com/2015/07/27/new-fcc-rules-may-prevent-installing-openwrt-on-wifi-routers/)

Below is an important part of the article.

> The new FCC rules are in effect in the United States from June 2nd 2015 for WiFi devices such as Access Points. They require to have the firmware locked down so End-Users can’t operate with non-compliant parameters (channels/frequencies, transmit power, DFS, …). In response, WiFi access point vendors start to lock down firmwares to prevent custom firmwares (such as OpenWRT) to be installed, using code signing, etc.

And my question is:
Are there any manufacturers which declared they will not follow the new rules and they will be manufacturing devices with unlocked firmwares so users can install open source firmwares like OpenWRT?
Background:
I never cared about my router till I read that new regulation. Now I want to choose the company which respects the "open" standard and declares that. I want to buy their devices, so they can earn and stay on the market.

Comment: Hello there! You're question is off-topic as it is not about applying open source principles or any issues. In fact, the question seems to be really asking what manufacturers are not following the law. The open source part seems to be only coincidental here. Also, the question seems to be asking for a hardware request. Sorry about that and the confusions :|

Comment: @Zizouz212 Hello. This is not an universal law, I don't live in US so it does not apply to me, besides of that I want to support those manufacturers. Can you recommend better SE community for that question?

Comment: I had asked the moderators at Law SE if this question was a good fit, but it's off-topic there. Assuming that you are looking for a manufacturer/product, there's a new [Hardware Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287/hardware-recommendations) proposal that is supposed to launch within 6 to 8 weeks. Hope that helps :D

Comment: I believe there is definitely a very good on-topic question in here, but a list of manufacturers who will not follow the rules isn't it. I'm not sure what is though.